# Substring output for different cases

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I need output with following cases:

```
+-----------------+--------+
| STRING in table | OUTPUT |
+-----------------+--------+
| NONGL_NONGL     | NONGL  |
| GL252_GL252     | GL     |
| GL400_GL400     | GL     |
| NOS_NOS         | NOS    |
+-----------------+--------+
```

I tried to use `SUBSTRING()` but it is not giving me proper output.

Comment: We need sample data and desired outputs, also what did you try so far

Comment: I had provided sample data. 
 implementing    
 SUBSTRING(COL_NAME,1,CHARINDEX('_',COL_NAME)- 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for the `NONGL` and `NOS` result you need:

```
SELECT LEFT([col_name], CHARINDEX('_', [col_name]) - 1)
```

And for the `GL` output, since the string is containing numbers you need `PATINDEX()`:

```
SELECT LEFT([col_name], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [col_name]) - 1)
```

In the end just use a `CASE WHEN`

```
DECLARE @tbl Table (string VARCHAR(MAX) );

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('NONGL_NONGL'),
('GL252_GL252'),
('GL400_GL400'),
('NOS_NOS');


SELECT
    string
    ,CASE WHEN 
        string LIKE '%[0-9]%' then LEFT(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', string) - 1)
        ELSE LEFT(string, CHARINDEX('_', string) - 1)
    END AS [Output]
from @tbl
```

Comment: Why you need a `SELECT`?

Comment: Yeah, was useless, I copied the query's from above when I edited the answer with full solution. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
select (case when col like 'NONGL%' then 'NONGL'
             when col like 'GL%' then 'GL'
             when col like 'NOS%' then 'NOS'
        end) as new_col
```

Comment: Looking for dynamic solution. I have multiple cases but format for COL_NAME is same.

Comment: @SwapnilV . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  If you have a different question, you should ask a question that has a good explanation, proper sample data and desired results.  The downvote is really rude, even though it didn't come from you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Agreed

Comment: Actually I was having multiple cases but pattern was same that's why provided sample cases. Will keep in mind ahead. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
DECLARE @StrTable Table (Str VARCHAR(MAX) );

INSERT INTO @StrTable VALUES
('NONGL_NONGL'),
('GL252_GL252'),
('GL400_GL400'),
('NOS_NOS');

SELECT Str, 
IIF(Str LIKE 'NONGL%','NONGL',IIF(Str LIKE 'GL%', 'GL', IIF(Str LIKE 'NOS%', 'NOS', Str))) AS Outputs
FROM @StrTable;
```

Result:

```
+-------------+---------+
|     Str     | Outputs |
+-------------+---------+
| NONGL_NONGL | NONGL   |
| GL252_GL252 | GL      |
| GL400_GL400 | GL      |
| NOS_NOS     | NOS     |
+-------------+---------+
```